# Estimate for de Bruijn function with small fixed smoothness bound

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, smoothness

Let $\Psi(x,B)$ denote the number of $B$-smooth numbers less than $x$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number#Distribution) gives the following "good estimate" for small, fixed $B$:

$$\Psi(x,B) \sim  \frac{1}{\pi(B)!} \prod_{p\le B}\frac{\log x}{\log p}$$

However, no citation or further discussion is given. Where does this estimate come from? How good an estimate is it? Anyone know a reference for this?

Comment: This is just from looking at the volume of $\sum_{p\le B} x_p \log p \le \log x$ with $x_p \ge 0$.   Look in Granville's survey on smooth numbers for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in chapter III.5 of Tenenbaum *Intro to analytic and probabilistic number theory* (Cambridge, 1995).  The estimate up to a factor $1+O(B^2/\log x\log B)$ uniform in $2 \le B \le \sqrt{\log x\log\log x}$ is attributed to Ennola 1969.

Comment: Any info on what happens for larger B? I'm interested in B closer to log(x)

Comment: The distribution for any range is explained both in Tenenbaum and Granville.